# Word wrap not working on my UILabel

Tags: xcode, swift, constraints, word-wrap

My app uses a custom cell to display products in a tableview. The product name when used on an iPhone 5 was running off the end so I set it to wrap
            which doesn't work. Each cell is populated in my Customcell class using the code below, I've added a couple of lines to the brandTxt label which again does not work.

```
public func configure(#text: String?, placeholder: String) {
    if (placeholder == "1")
    {
        brandItemLabel.text = text
        brandItemLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        brandItemLabel.numberOfLines = 2
    }
    else if (placeholder == "2")
    {
        brandSmallLabel.text = text

    }
    else if (placeholder == "3")
    {
        uomCodeLabel.text = text

    }
    else if (placeholder == "4")
    {
        codeLabel.text = text

    }
    else if (placeholder == "6")
    {
        var image = UIImage(named: "Blank.jpg")
        if let url = NSURL(string: text!) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }
        var imgViewLbl = UIImageView(image: image) as UIImageView
        imgViewLbl.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 4, width: 90, height: 90)
        customView.addSubview(imgViewLbl)
    }
}
```

I've also tried using constraints but that is not working either

I've since added the code below using preferredMaxLayoutWidth as well as setting the Preferred Width to Explicit in Size Manager and added Constraints to set the size and height as well as the position.

```
public func configure(#text: String?, placeholder: String) {
    if (placeholder == "1")
    {
        brandItemLabel.text = text
        brandItemLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        brandItemLabel.numberOfLines = 2
        brandItemLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 330
    }
```

The UILabel is still not wrapping in spite of these changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are targeting iOS 6 until 8 or higher, you have to explicitly set the preferredWidth attribute on the UILabel. You have to do it, if the label has more than one line. See also [preferredMaxLayoutWidth:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/preferredMaxLayoutWidth)

So you just need to specify this value (in most cases it's good to go to the storyboard, click on the label, go to the "Size Inspector" and just click on 'explicit' next to "Preferred Width").

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I set the preferred width to explicit in the size inspector and also added the line brandItemLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 330 in my code in Customcell but unfortunately it still isn't wrapping. Could it be anything to do with the Customcell set up?

Comment: did you also set constraints to your label? Can show us a screenshot or something? Did you also try to set it up to a smaller value? I think preferredWidth is only working when you use constraints. So you also need to specify the height (e.g. with a constraint)

Comment: I've tried constraints but not a smaller size which I'll try now. I'm happy to send you a screenshot if you let me have your email address.

Comment: can you just upload it somewhere and post here a link (e.g. on http://postimage.org/)? What exactly happens? Does the label just display the text in one line and goes beyond the cell bounds?

Comment: Hi Chuck, your suggestion worked, it was my bad as I was feeding in the short description instead of the proper one. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Checking `Follow Readable Width` in Size Inspector and setting larger height, did it for me!